# Is it possible to use gradients in emails?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Is it possible to use gradients on elements in newsletter emails, using CSS? Is the full property supported?

Comment: What do you mean with `the full tag`?

Comment: yaa i mean with the full tag

Comment: I still don't understand. What tag are you referring to? There is no HTML `<full>` tag that I know of?

Comment: no i am creating a news letter and i want to use its background color with the gradient color so can it is possible to support the gradient background color.

Answer (score 10):

In short, no.

Email clients very rarely support HTML5 or CSS3, and so it will break in any clients that don't.

You could always have a fallback, but the load time won't change too much, and adding CSS3 simply adds more code to keep track of.

I would recommend using image tags and hosting the images on your server, and that's if you really have to use gradients at all.

With email, generally the simpler the better. Personally, I prefer recieving plain text.

Comment: Agree that it will likely have very limited support, but there would be no harm in using it, and fall back to a solid background-color in those that doesn't - like your would on a web page. It will not break the email in that sense, it will just not show the gradient.

Comment: @Alfo Do you have any specific information that you base your answer on? Could you specify "very rarely"?

Comment: An answer from 4 years ago, not updated, has very little value.

Answer (score 8):

Support for CSS gradients has improved nowadays in email clients, something like this will work in the majority:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), transparent);
```

Outlook on Windows doesn't support that, but you can use VML (Vector Markup Language) to make it work there too, i.e.:

```html
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;">
  <v:fill type="gradient" color="#0072FF" color2="#00C6FF" angle="90" />
  <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">            
  <div><![endif]-->
  Text over gradient
<!--[if gte mso 9]></div></v:textbox></v:rect><![endif]-->
```

I wrote a guide on [gradients in email](https://maizzle.com/guides/css-background-gradients-html-emails/) for the Maizzle framework, it also shows how to do body background gradients in Outlook, and a few other tips.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here's my go-to resource for CSS support in email: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

It doesn't have specific info for background gradients, and since this falls under the `background-image` property. My hunch would be that there's inconsistent, if any, support amongst email clients as it is a fairly feature to CSS. My only hesitation is that I think a background gradient is treated as `background-image`, which seems to have decent support except for Outlook.