# Is it possible somehow to use linear-gradient into mails viewed by outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I know that outlook doesn't support css linear gradient - but is it possible in some different way to use it ?

Comment: use it as an image

Comment: it's difficult, because I want to use overlaped button

Comment: Someone mentioned using VML to make this work in outlook.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62324025/9288348

Comment: I've tried it too and unfortunately without success.

Comment: Please show the VML code you tried, because it can work. Maybe there's a small error somewhere, but we can't tell unless we see your code.

Comment: You can use VML (as @Nathan mentioned) and also use gradient. Here is a link to see which devices support either of the two gradients: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=gradient

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor so it applies its own restrictions to the markup that you could use for message bodies. The best way to implement the required linear gradient is to use an image(s). You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.